# How can i rotate 2D (x,y) pixels around x axis?

Tags: math, opengl, graphics, matrix, rotation

Which matrix should i use?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_anglestoaxes.html

There are derived matrices at bottom `Axis Rotations` , what are the usage of those matrices.
I can't understand the difference of those those, when to use what?

Why are derived matrices calculated?

Or when to use this?

[image: img]

and when to use this?

[image: img2]

Comment: For 2D, use the wikipedia one.  All the others are for 3D.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which one?

Comment: You can't rotate 2D pixels around the X axis; you need 3 dimensions in order to preform that rotation.

Comment: So when is this used? http://i.imgur.com/gTVuk.png ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_2D_graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2D, you are using the X and Y axis. To do a rotation in 2D, you'll want to rotate on the Z axis, so that your points move on the X and Y axis. Use the Z-axis rotation matrix.

The X, Y, and Z axis rotation matrices are merely the simplified form of the other equation that has many more trigonometric functions involved. If you look at that one and plug in 0 for any of the two variables, you'll see it simplifies into one of the three axis specific versions.

Edit: Use the one with the Z in it. The third of the simpler versions.

Comment: You answer is not specific, can you be more specific? Which matrix should i use?

Comment: R_z(theta) (which really is the canonical 2D rotation matrix embedded in a 3x3 matrix).

Comment: R_z(theta)? Are you sure? It should be R_x(theta) if you want to rotate around X axis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix